# Properly set / match routes in routes.rb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I've implemented basic tagging in my app, so posts can be filtered by tags.

There's a route in my routes.rb for that

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'links#index', as: :tag
```

However, I would like to have an URL /tags that lists all tags (triggers index action in the tag controller).

I've set this route up

```
get 'tags' => 'tags#index'
```

In my tag view i have `index.html.erb`

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div class="row">
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that `<%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>` leads to `/tags/:id` instead of `/tags/:tag` and thus doesn't work.

How do I properly set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/to_param) method to your `Tag` model:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to match something like `tags/tag-name`, with `tag-name` being a field other than `id` on `Tags`; you can use [friendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Comment: This line "get 'tags/:tag', to: 'links#index', as: :tag" works like that. When I click on tag named for example 'test', it takes me to ../tags/test.

How do I make that work while indexing tags?

Comment: In your Tags controller you'd find the tag like `Tag.find_by(name: tag)` or something of that sort.